# Sliding from side with jquery (without Jquery UI)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I want to make `specialist_pagecontent` to appear (slide) from the left, like `blindleftin` from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/65QsU/) but I just can't make it work with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Jwkw6/). Actually, the plan is, instead of `hide()` ideal would be `blindLeftOut('fast');hide()`, and instead of `show()` I need `show();blindLeftOut('slow')`, but as I said, I just can't make blindLeftOut and blindLeftIn work for me.

Comment: I combined the 2 fiddles making the calls to blindLeftOut and blindLeftIn work. See my answer for details and let me know if that is what you were looking for. Also, is that a typo in your question regarding `and instead of show() I need show();blindLeftOut('slow')`? Should that not be `and instead of show() I need show();blindLeftIn('slow')` instead, seeing it's replacing show and `blindLeftIn` is for showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the elements you want to animate in and out a `viweport`. A layer through which you look to see the elements within. Then set this `viewport`'s `overflow` property to `hidden` and give it a specific width/height.

This way you can animate the elements within the `viewport` so they appear to slide in/out.

Here are the changes I'd make to your JS:

```
//notice the use of the "active" class to save state
$('.specialist_pagecontent').eq(0).addClass("active").animate({ left : 0 }, 500);
$('.specialist').click(function() {  
    //stop() is used to stop the current animation, so animations don't queue up if many buttons are clicked rapidly
    $('.specialist_pagecontent').filter(".active").removeClass("active").stop(true).animate({ left : '-100%' }, 500); 
    $('.selected-specialist').removeClass('selected-specialist');
    $(this).addClass('selected-specialist');
     $('.specialist_pagecontent').eq($(this).index('.specialist')).addClass("active").stop(true).animate({ left : 0 }, 500);
});
```

And here are my suggested edits to the CSS:

```
.specialist_pagecontent {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:-100%;
}
#specialist_lists {
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Jwkw6/1/

This absolutely positions the elements that are to be animated, which is very useful since it removes the elements from the regular flow of the document (meaning it won't trigger whole page redraws when it animates). This also creates the `viewport` I mentioned, creating a window into which we look to see the animations.

Comment: appreciate the effort, but div with "specialist_pagecontent" divs should stay at right of "specialists" div

Comment: @Flyer The reason the `.specialist_pagecontent` divs drop below the buttons is because there isn't enough space horizontally, I actually didn't do anything but give the `#specialist_lists` div a specified width, which can easily be tweaked to match your UI.

Comment: I feel stupid, really. This looks pretty good. Only thing left to figure out is height of specialist_lists since it will "dynamic"

Comment: @Flyer You can use `overflow-x : hidden` and `overflow-y : visible` on the `viewport` element so the height can be dynamic. The support for these properties is good (IE 6 may give you trouble).

Comment: Works great. Thanks a lot. Didn't know about overflow-y & overflow-x

Answer (score 4):

I think jQuery's [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function might be of use to you.

What you'd need to do is either have a hidden div positioned out of the window added to your HTML (or maybe add it dynamically using jquery on `document.ready` event, if you prefer) and the use the above mentioned animate function to slide it in and out and bind it to the menu item's click function.

## Working Fiddle

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QPhB3/) for you